# Stop submitting form multiple times by jquery on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am submitting a form using jquery submit() function but it's submitting multiple time. i used everything i know but not able to stop it.
Below is my function :

```
function submit(){
    $("#save").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#loader").modal('show');
    $("#save").off('click');
    if($("#name").val() == ''){
        alert("Please Enter Name!");
        $("#save").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#save").on('click', submit);
        $("#loader").modal('hide');  
        return false;
    }
    // Other validations as well
    $("#form").submit();  
}

$("#save").off('click').on('click', submit);
```

Below is my form:

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <button type="button" id="save">save</button>
</form>
```

But sometime click working multiple time if user click button multiple time too fast. not every time. anyone have any idea?

Comment: Well I see 3 submits in your code, how about you start from there?

Comment: @ikiK thanks for reply, i updated my question with the HTML as well. can you please check now. on click of button i am calling my user defined submit method and inside submit method i am submitting my form by jquery submit method.

Comment: Consider using [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: @freedomn-m .one() only work once but for me if user didn't fill the user name then he will never able to submit the form.

Comment: Within the click hander, 3rd thing you do is `$("#save").off('click');` - then you add it again.  That's what `.one` would do for your - remove the `.off` and *replace* the `.on` (and .off().on()`) with `.one` - it's not meant to be used *once* - it's meant to be used where you're doing it manually.

Comment: A form can only submit once using default submit process so this really doesn't make sense. Do you have other listeners for the submit event also?

Comment: @freedomn-m got your point. let me try it.

Comment: @charlietfl but if button clicked multiple time then the click event fired multiple and form will submit multiple time as well.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, your are right. my form is not submitting by default process.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, it's looks like working for me. i misunderstood the jquery .one().

Comment: Then show us how the other code works. If it is in a submit event handler you should be doing this all in one place and not over complicating it

Comment: This looks like it would be better served in `$("form").on("submit", function....` then if you want to submit form using http/form post (rather than ajax) you would do `$("form")[0].submit()` at the end (ie the vanilla js submit, not the jquery submit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that comes to mind, is to add a className to the "Save" button on click, and check for this className in your callback, if the class exists, return, else submit. Something like the following:

```
function submit(){
    const $saveBtn = $('#save');
    //if the button has been clicked already, return
    if($saveBtn.hasClass('clicked'){
        return;
    }else{ //add the class to prevent multiple submission
       $saveBtn.addClass('clicked');
    }
    $saveBtn.prop('disabled', true);
    .......
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you say the above solution of adding a className doesn't work, use a global boolean:

at the top of your script declare the boolean:

```
let submitted = false;

function submit(){
    //if the boolean is true, return
    if(submitted){
        return;
    }else{ //set to true
        submitted = true;
    }
    const $saveBtn = $('#save');
    $saveBtn.prop('disabled', true);
    .......
}
```

Comment: Nice answer but in my case it's not working sometime it clicked twice before class added to the button. thanks for the answer any other full proof idea you have?

Comment: @Jeevan Try it with a boolean then, declare it globally at the beginning of your script and then toggle it to true on first click, see updated answer.

Comment: this answer is also working for me. accepting as an answer for other but most reliable answer is jquery .one() method and attach it if needed. Thanks @Ryan